# Optimal Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Okay, trying to figure out how to output the optimal binary search tree with the given data.

I've found the dynamic programming table and the root table already (code attached), and now I need to output the tree with the roots found.

I have a bit of pseudocode designed to help me figure out this function, but nothing I try works.

```
Pseudocode:

PrintTree(roots[][], i, j, space_needed)
{
    if(i <= j)
    {
         print <space_needed> and then roots[i][j];

         PrintTree(roots[][], i, roots[i][j] - 1, space_needed++);

         PrintTree(roots[][], roots[i][j] + 1, j, space_needed++);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you perhaps please place your code in here, as there was no attachment on the post that I saw for the root table.

Comment: I think you want `space_needed+1` rather than `space_needed++`. The way you have it right now, the second child will have more indentation than the first.

Comment: Stanford Coursera course problem? ;)